# How to stop timer of form1 when form2 button is clicked

Tags: c#

I have a timer running on my form1 and i want that when i click on the button of form2 then it will stop .How can i do this .Anyone here for help. The is the  timer start code .

```
        //timer1.Start();
        //picboxstart.Image = Resources.puse;

        panelwork.BackColor = Color.MediumSeaGreen;
        lbltime.ForeColor = Color.White;
        if (t.Enabled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sure !!! Your Start time is been Registered...", "Success Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            //lblstarttime.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

            try
            {

                string sql = "INSERT INTO Todaywork(Username,Start_time,Date,Total_time,TodayDate)VALUES('" + lblusrname.Text + "','" + lbltime.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" + lbltime.Text + "','"+DateTime.Now+"')";



                if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                    conn.Open();

                command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);


                int x = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                conn.Close();


            }
```

So i want to stop timer when i click on form2 button.plz help

Comment: Your code doesn't have any timers

Comment: Dear Mention above. The timer and then i enabled it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the relation between `Form1` and `Form2`? If `Form2` is opened via the button in `Form1`, you can achieve it by define a custom property `PropertyTimer` to get the `timer1` instance.

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    int i = 0;

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i++);
    }

    private void btOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.PropertyTimer = timer1;
        form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Form2.cs

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Timer PropertyTimer { get; set; }

    private void btStopTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

If there is no relation between them, here is a general method that using [Application.OpenForms Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.openforms?view=netcore-3.1).

Here is the steps:

First, define a property `timer` in `Form1.cs` to get the `timer1 instance`.

```
public Timer timer
{
    get { return timer1; }
    set { timer1 = value; }
}
```

Then, access the timer via `Application.OpenForms Property` in `Form2.cs`.

```
private void btStopTimer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 f1 = (Form1)(Application.OpenForms["Form1"]);
    f1.timer.Stop();
}
```